# How to set blank=False in Django form without a Model

Tags: django, django-forms

I made a Django form by extending forms.Form without a database model. How can i set blank=False on a CharField so that Django validation will check for me wheteher the field is empty or not?

EDIT:
In views.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        #####
        #####
    else:
        form=LoginForm()
        buttontext='Login'
        return render(request,'index.html',{'buttontext':buttontext,'form':form})
```

In forms.py:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username=forms.CharField(label="Username",max_length=30,blank=False)
    password=forms.CharField(label="Password",widget=forms.PasswordInput(),blank=False)
    class Meta:
        help_texts={'username':None,}
    def clean(self):
        self.cleaned_data=super(LoginForm,self).clean()
        u=self.cleaned_data['username']
        try:
            us=Account.objects.all().get(username=u)
            p=self.cleaned_data['password']
            print 'original:', us.password
            print 'got:', p
            if p!=us.password:
                add_error('password','Incorrect password')
        except Account.DoesNotExist:
            self.add_error('username','Username does not exist!')
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: Please share your forms.py and views.py code for clarity.

Comment: I **really** hope that you aren't storing passwords in plain text here. Delete all this code immediately and use the built-in Django auth system.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I know password shall not be saved in plain text, it is rather hashed. But this is only a test project. I am just learning django. I am not assigned any production level projects yet. I really have to learn to use the built-in auth library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to point out @Daniel Roseman's comment above - don't use this form for saving passwords, at least [not how you're doing it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords). For *other* forms though: You want `required`, not `blank`. Blank is for models, [required is for forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#required).

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username=forms.CharField(label="Username",max_length=30,required=False)
    password=forms.CharField(label="Password",widget=forms.PasswordInput(),required=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is only a test project. I know password should be stored as a hashed value. I have to learn the djabgo's built-in auth package.

Answer (score 1):

use required=True instead of blank=False

e.g:

```
username=forms.CharField(label="Username",max_length=30,required=True)
```

In Django, blank=False in models correlates to required=True in forms.